# how to use prepared statement effectively?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Login
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException
    {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        Statement st = null;
        try {
            Driver driver = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
            DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
            System.out.println("coneecting to the database:");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("driverURL","usrr","pass");
            System.out.println("creating statement");
            String sql = "Update abhi SET age = ? WHERE id = ?";
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setInt(1, 35);
            stmt.setInt(2,102);
            int rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
            S.O.P("rows updated"+rows);
            stmt.close();
            String sql2;
            sql2 = "select * from abhi";
            st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql2);
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println("hi");
                int age = rs.getInt("age");
                System.out.println("age is"+age);
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (st != null)
                    st.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                 // nthing to do
            }
            try {
                if(con != null)
                    con.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("good bye johny");
    }
}
```

this is my  code its runing prefectly without any error ...but in my database its nt
           updating the values i am unable to understand the reason does any body help me 
           with that why its nt updating the value of age where id is 102 ...

Comment: I don't see a commit. (Please try and format your code, it's really hard to follow as you posted it.)

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);


con.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle,

The default database transaction mode is two-phase commit.

i.e. after inserting or updating the data,

you should explicitly commit the operation, to persist data in your oracle db.

But here, I have not seen any commit in your code.

May You check this issue in your code?

You should use -

`con.setAutoCommit(false);` at begining of the code

and

```
con.commit(); to commit the data
```

Comment: coneecting to the database:
creating statement
good bye johny
i am only getting this o/p even i used above 1 .........con.commit after update query

Comment: i AM STILL UNABLE TO UNDERSTAND THE PROBLEM IN MY CODE ... I HAVE INCLUDED THE CON.COMMIT() AFTER STMT.EXECUTEuPDATE();

Comment: If the number of updated rows is 0, that simply means that there is no row with ID=102 in the table. Check your data. Check you're connecting to the correct database. Check that the data you're looking at in your database browser is committed data.

Comment: I CHECK IT SEVERAL TIMES EVN I MAKE A NEW TABLE AND INSERT 102 AS ID BUT UNABLE TO UNDERSTAND ANYTHING.EVN ITS NT PRINTING ANY VALUE ON CONSOLE OF AGE.

Comment: plz any body review my code and tell me exact where i done wrong.

Comment: Your code isn't wrong. If it doesn't print anything, that means there is no row in the table. DO you connect on the same host, with the same user and password, in your database browser? Also, NO NEED TO SHOUT!

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, try to use **connection commit** like this.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Login
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException
{
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    Statement st = null;
    try
    {
        Driver driver = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
        System.out.println("coneecting to the database:");

    con = DriverManager.getConnection("driverURL","usrr","pass");       
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    System.out.println("creating statement");

    String sql = "Update abhi SET age = ? WHERE id = ?";

    stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    stmt.setInt(1, 35);

    stmt.setInt(2,102);

    int rows =    stmt.executeUpdate();

    S.O.P("rows updated"+rows);

    stmt.close();
    con.commit();
    String sql2;

    sql2 = "select * from abhi";

    st = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql2);

    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println("hi");


        int age = rs.getInt("age");

        System.out.println("age is"+age);
    }

                 rs.close();

    stmt.close();

    con.close();
}

catch(SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e)
         {
    e.printStackTrace();    
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        if(st!=null)
            st.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e) 
    {
               // nthing to do

                 }
    try
    {
        if(con!=null)

        con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

                e.printStackTrace();

                 }


         }

       System.out.println("good bye johny");

        }
```

Comment: thanks everyone but i got it  i hve done some mistake in writing query